# How to cold call/post a long lost relative?

Tags: family, personal-information, estranged-relations

My mother lost touch with her cousins many years ago and I would have been about 5 years old the last time I seen them. I am 30 now.

I am doing family research and trying to build the family tree. My mother is quite a bit younger than her cousins so she doesn't remember much.

I found a few of them on Facebook but the others don't use Facebook. Some are not really interested much in my research and are not providing much info about my great-grandparents but they might not remember either. It's a long shot but I'd like to ask them about the family history.

I looked up their name in the phone book and I think I may have found them but I have no way of verifying the info from the phone book because some of the cousins are estranged from each other due to family issues.

I want to write a letter to the address in the phone book (essentially cold-calling/mailing) and see if it's my relative. I don't want to reveal too much in case it is not my mother's cousin after all.

Some of them would be 60+ so I'm not sure if they use email or not.
Here's what I've thought of, but I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, or if  I should explain more.

> Hi XYZ,
>
> Are you ABC & EFG's son? I am so-and-so, your cousin HIG's daughter.
>
> If you are the right one could you please email me back at:
>   myemail@email.com?
>
> Regards,
>
> so-and-so

**How can I ask some long lost relatives if they indeed are family members without revealing too much information about us?**

Comment: Hi user1261710. I've edited your OP in order to remove some off-topic part, and, hopefully, phrase your main concern so it becomes a question we can help you with (more on topic). Please let us know if it's good for you, and feel free to edit/rollback yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the general idea of your letter is perfectly fine, though I would modify it slightly to be a little more formal and add some more info. I recommend more formal, because letters in general tend to be more formally written, and you are addressing a stranger who is from an older generation. I also recommend mentioning the reason you are contacting them so that they aren't worrying trying to figure out why a distant relative is reaching out. You don't have to go into detail; just saying that you are trying to research the family history is enough to be helpful without revealing anything private.

> Hi XYZ,
>
> My name is so-and-so. I am trying to do some research on my family
>   history, and I believe you are my mother, HIJ's, cousin. Are you the
>   son of ABC & EFG? If so, I would be interested in talking with you to
>   try and learn more about my family history. Could you please let me know if you'd be willing to talk or not, or if I have the wrong person? You can email me at myemail@email.com, or if you prefer, call or text me at 555-555-555.
>
> Regards, so-and-so

Comment: +1 for asking for a reply *even if its the wrong person*. Instead of waiting forever, you might know quickly to keep searching, or stop persuing that person